# How to setup wildcard in react router root directory

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react router with `Switch` and loading content via react lazy. I need to pass wildcard on the root directory as well have other page such as `/about` or `/contact` etc. I have tried with following code:

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
      <Suspense fallback={<span className={'mx-auto w-50 d-block'}>Loading....</span>}>
        <Route exact path={'/'} component={Welcome} />
        <Route path={'/signup'} render={(props) => <SignupPage {...props} user={user} />} />
        <Route path={'/login'} component={LoginPage} />
        <Route path={'/dashboard'} component={(props) => <Dashboard {...props} user={user} />} />
        <Route path={'/my-kitchen'} render={(props) => <KitchenDoor {...props} user={user} />} />
        <Route path={'/counter'} render={(props) => <KitchenCounter {...props} user={user} />} />
        <Route path={'/logout'} render={(props) => <LogoutPage {...props} user={user} />} />
        <Route path={'/contact'} render={(props) => <ContactPage {...props} user={user} />} />
        <Route exact path={'/:customer'} render={(props) => <Customers {...props} user={user} />} />
      </Suspense>
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

Home page working fine. But as soon as I try to visit login page or contact or any other (except `:/customer`), it tries to render `Customer` component.

Please help.

Cheers.

Comment: Does it work without the `Suspense` component ? Because according to [documentation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Switch.md#children-node) `All children of a <Switch> should be <Route> or <Redirect> elements. Only the first child to match the current location will be rendered.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried your example and just worked fine with the following changes:

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

const history = createBrowserHistory();

// ...

<Router history={history}>
   <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading ...</div>}>
      <Switch>                  
         <Route exact path={'/'} component={(props) => <div>Home</div>} />
         <Route path={'/signup'} render={(props) => <div>SignupPage</div>} />
         <Route path={'/login'} component={(props) => <div>LoginPage</div>} />
         <Route path={'/about'} component={(props) => <div>About</div>} />
         <Route path={'/dashboard'} component={(props) => <div>dashboard</div>} />
         <Route path={'/my-kitchen'} render={(props) => <div>KitchenDoor</div>} />
         <Route path={'/counter'} render={(props) => <div>KitchenCounter</div>} />
         <Route path={'/logout'} render={(props) => <div>LogoutPage</div> } />
         <Route path={'/contact'} render={(props) => <div>ContactPage</div>} />
         <Route exact path={'/:customer'} render={(props) => <div>Customers</div>} />
      </Switch>
   </Suspense>
</Router>
```

I have changed in my code the following:

1. to render `<div>component name</div>` only because I did not have the implementation of your components.
2. the order of how you are using `<Suspense>` and `<Switch>` under `<Router>`.
3. added `path={'/about'}` route which was missing.

I have tested out with `Router` and it was rendering as expected in each cases what you mentioned:

1. http://localhost:3000/login => LoginPage
2. http://localhost:3000/:123 => Customers
3. http://localhost:3000/about => About
4. http://localhost:3000/contact => ContactPage

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, @norbitrial you are awesome mate. its working. but I don't want `hash` in my url. does it have to like this? plz suggest.

Comment: @jahid Not really, it was just in my example where I have tried these out. It should work with `Router` as well. Let me now how that works, if you have still issues we can take a quick look. Thanks!

Comment: sorry mate its not working. Also I didn't notice before, with `hashrouter` when I visit customer `/:2` or `/:4` it renders home component. not what I want.

Comment: sorry mate, I got it fixed. in my code I had `switch` wrapping the `Suspense`. but it should have been other way around. working now mate. thank you so much.

Comment: @jahid Great! Additionally I have implemented with `Router` just to have exactly the same solution what you need.

Comment: thanks mate, its working perfectly now. Learning something new from you today mate. God bless you.